# Compactness of a union of compact sets along a compact set in a product space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and $K \subset X$ compact. Suppose also we have some compact sets $F_x$ for each $x \in K$.

Let $M:= \bigcup\limits_{x \in K} \{ x \} \times F_x \subset X \times Y$. Is $M$ necessarily compact? Are there conditions on $X$ and $Y$ that make it necessarily compact? For example, if $X$ is a manifold and $Y = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=[0,1]$ denote the unit interval. Consider this example: $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $K=I$, and
$$
F_x=\begin{cases}I &\text{ if } x \text{ is rational;} \\
\{0\} &\text{ if } x \text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $M$ is not compact in $X\times Y=\mathbb R^2$; in fact, it is not closed.

I think the problem here is that the fibers $\{F_x\}$ are completely irrelevant to each other --- It is relatively easy to construct counterexamples when there is no constraint on these compact sets.